# Stored procedure returning an entry with null values (when it's not)

Tags: c#, sql-server, api, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

For some reason, when I try to perform a query (through an API) with the entry's id, I get access where it contains null attributes. But, if I perform a question using other attributes (besides ID), it has the correct values.

For example: when I perform (the actual stored procedure code):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spClient_GetById]
    @Id int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Client
    WHERE Id = @Id;
END
```

I get the entry

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "email": null,
    "phoneNumber": null,
    "houseNum": "1212",
    "street": "Downtown",
    "state": "WA",
    "city": "Vancouver",
    "cost": 12000.0000,
    "status": "Started",
    "eta": 0,
    "startDate": null,
    "completeDate": null,
    "contractorID": 0
}
```

But when I perform the following query on the same database,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spClient_GetByHouse]
    @HouseNum nvarchar(10),
    @Street nvarchar(50) = null
AS
    IF @Street IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Client
        WHERE HouseNum = @HouseNum;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Client
        WHERE HouseNum = @HouseNum AND Street LIKE @Street;
    END
```

I get the following entry (same entry btw):

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "This",
    "lastName": "That",
    "email": "qwe@yahoo.com",
    "phoneNumber": "3603602334",
    "houseNum": "1212",
    "street": "Downtown",
    "state": "WA",
    "city": "Vancouver",
    "cost": 12000.0000,
    "status": "Started",
    "eta": 0,
    "startDate": null,
    "completeDate": null,
    "contractorID": 1
}
```

Additionally, if I perform the SQL code in SQL Server, it returns all the correct values. So, the problem is when I'm calling that stored procedure through an API it's returning null values when it should.

Also, the first name, last name, and phone numbers defined to not allow nulls in the schema

More info: here's the function of calling the query my ID stored procedure:

```
public async Task<ClientModel> GetProjectById(int id)
{
    var records = await _dataAccess.LoadData<ClientModel, dynamic>("dbo.spClient_GetById", new { Id = id },
                                                                        _connectionString.SqlConnectionName);
    return records.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And here's the function for calling the query by other attributes:

```
public async Task<ClientModel> GetProjectByHouse(string house, string? street)
{
    var p = new { HouseNum = house, Street = street };
    var records = await _dataAccess.LoadData<ClientModel, dynamic>("dbo.spClient_GetByHouse", p,
                                                                        _connectionString.SqlConnectionName);
    return trimValues(records.FirstOrDefault());
    // return records.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And here's the API function for calling either previous functions:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int? projectId, string? house, string? street)
{
    if (projectId != null)
    {
        var project = await _clientData.GetProjectById(projectId ?? default(int));

        if (project == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(project);
    }
    else if (house != null)
    {
        if (house.Length < 2)
            return BadRequest();

        var project = await _clientData.GetProjectByHouse(house, street);

        if (project == null)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(project);
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: "when I try to perform a query (through an API)".  Can you post the C# code that calls the stored proc and returns unexpected nulls?  I see nothing wrong with the T-SQL (ignoring SELECT * is evil).

Comment: Agreed there is no C# here at all, only json (which is strange to say the least), and raw sql.

Comment: @Zer0 sorry, just added the code. Hope that helps on tracking down the bug!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the C# code either and it's bizarre considering you're effectively calling the stored procs the same way.  That said, I have no idea what `_dataAccess` is and what `LoadData` does.  Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?  If the schema has those columns marked NOT NULL, it can't be the database.  Something is getting lost in translation.

Comment: @Zer0 I believe that is the class to perform the store procedure and data type conversion (I learned it from a tutorial but don't quite fully understand it myself). Additionally, the query function is part of a library injection so I have no clue have to step debug a DLL

Comment: I'm not sure if this is appropriate for SO, but you can step through code like that using other tools such as .NET Reflector (commercial software).  That's what I would do if you don't have the source.  This is basically conjecture, but I'd put my money on `LoadData` (and lower in that stack) being the problem.

Comment: The two stored procedures do two different things. In one you pass the "@id" and get the data from dbo.Client. In the second one you pass the "@HouseNum" and get the records from dbo.Client. What happens if you run the stored procedures in SSMS by passing the "@id"=2 for first sp and "@HouseNum"=2

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph using  the SSMS with the problem store procedure code gives the right result. Also when I do HouseNum = 2 I get no results (as it should be) and when I do Id =2 it returns the entry with values instead of null

Comment: I would double check if the db being connected in C# is the same as where you are running the code. Another option to see is what the values are being passed to stored procedure by writing a logging procedure

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this was what solved it (but the problem is fixed). I had to delete the old db and republish a new one.

Answer (score 0):

There is two case which I found

1. Case sensitive the alias need to be same with model.
2. In stored procedures, if a column has data type integer, then the model must also have the same type.